# Jenkins: Permission issue using Docker as build environment

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I installed Jenkins on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The Jenkins itself is not run in a container. What I want to do is simply call `yarn install` using a node image. So here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('install node modules...') {
            agent { docker 'node' }
            steps {
                sh 'cd /path/to/package.json; yarn install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward, right?

jenkins user/group is `112:116`, and the uid of the node container is `1000`, hence yarn process (which is run as node user 1000) can't do its things, like `mkdir /.config`.

I tried to spin up the node container passing in argument `-u 1000`, it bumped into permission issues when trying to create durable directories.

It looks like one or the other kind of issue, how can I work around that?